# Setting up custom formats for respond_to and respond_with in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting a **ActionView::MissingTemplate** when trying to get a custom output to behave with respond_to/with like it behaves xml/json output.

I have a custom output format available on my object.

```
@item.to_custom
```

I've registered the format with a custom Mime::Type registered in the **mime_types.rb**.

```
Mime::Type.register "application/custom", :custom
```

I have it listed in my respond_to options in my controller

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :custom
```

And then I have a respond_with method before the end of my show action.

```
def show
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])    
  respond_with(@item) 
end
```

When I access items/1234.xml I get the xml output. When I try to access items/1234.custom I get an error **ActionView::MissingTemplate**. I can fix it by adding the file app/views/show.custom.ruby with the contents:

```
@item.to_custom
```

Is there a way to get to_custom to work like to_xml or to_json in a respond_to/with setup? To just use the to_custom method without needing a template? Or will I have to use a view template that calls the method explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to manually add a `Renderer` for your custom format if you want it to render without explicitly adding a view template.

The Rails built-in formats `xml` and `json` have renderers automatically added from within the Rails framework, which is why they work right out of the box and your custom format does not ([source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb#L95)).

Try adding this in an initializer or right below where you register your MIME type

```
# config/initializers/renderers.rb
ActionController::Renderers.add :foo do |object, options|
  self.content_type ||= Mime::FOO
  object.respond_to?(:to_foo) ? object.to_foo : object
end
```

NOTE: Don't use `custom` as your format name because it will conflict with a method in the `respond_with` internals.

There is an excellent blog post that explains building custom `Renderers` in depth here: http://beerlington.com/blog/2011/07/25/building-a-csv-renderer-in-rails-3/

Comment: Great! This worked like a charm. No worries on the name, custom was just a placeholder, but thanks for the keyword heads up.